# binding an List of objects to a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have the following XAML code

```
        <ListBox x:Name="TrackedProgramList" Height="145" Width="605" ItemsSource="  {Binding}" >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=programName}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I'm binding a List to the Listbox's ItemsSource.
The List contains "FileInfo" objects.
FileInfos is an object with some attributes like "programName", "manufacturer" etc.

The problem now is that the list only displays something like:

```
 Namespace.FileInfo
 Namespace.FileInfo
 Namespace.FileInfo
 ...
```

so i think that the path is incorrect.

Comment: `but i get the following error` what error....?

Comment: A guess as you never mentioned the error, but have a look at the BindingList

Comment: After your edit. Well... it seems unlikely... between `ListBox` and `/ListBox` tags there should be Items... and not a DataTemplate! Plus you are using ItemsSource so there should be nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error you are getting is probably:

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

There is **probably** no problem with binding.... your bigest problem is invalid xaml.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I guess you want to have listbox with horizonatal `Stackpanel` as `ItemsPanel`.

Then it should be like this:

```xml
<ListBox ... >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

And then you probably want to provide an `ItemTemplate`

```xml
<ListBox ... >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Border Background="Red" Width="150" Height="100">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=programName}" />
           </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**EDIT**

After you edited your question it seems that you have new problem. *Still... your XAML should not be working. If you used one you provided with your question. It's invalid.*

If you are getting result like:

```
Namespace.FileInfo
Namespace.FileInfo
Namespace.FileInfo
Namespace.FileInfo
```

then your binding in ItemTemplate is not working correctly. Make sure `programName` is public property.

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation.

As I said. My code works fine.

**UPDATE**

`List<FileInfo>` should be `ListBox`'s `DataContext`... it probably is... since you get this result. What you should check is that in `FileInfo` class is `programName` as public property.

It should be something like this.

```
public class FileInfo : ObservableObject
{
  private string _programName;

  public string programName
  {
      get{ return this._programName;}
      set
      {
          this._programName = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.programName);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. I tried your xaml with nearly the same result.
the properties are public: public List<FileInfo> trackings = new List<FileInfo>();

Comment: @Laokoon what you have written in your comment is not property and it's not what's important. That List<FileInfo> should be set as LisBox's DataContext... what should be public property is programName. See Update2

Comment: @Laokoon You probably don't need to have FileInfo class to inherit from ObservableObject. And there will be no RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: programName ist also public

Comment: @Laokoon As I said earlier... it's all working for me fine, so if you want to resolve your problem you should provide us with more info.